# Как изменить реализацию функции с рекурсии на итерацию?

Tags: lisp, функции

muLisp

```
(DEFUN MEMBER(ATM LST)
    (LOOP
        ((NULL LST) NIL)
        ((EQL ATM (CAR LST)))
        (SETQ LST (CDR LST)
    )
)
   (DEFUN UNION (LAMBDA (LST1 LST2)
   ; Функция UNION возвращает объединение ;
   ;          множеств LST1 и LST2        ;
      (COND ( (NULL LST1) LST2 )
            ( (MEMBER (CAR LST1) LST2)
                (UNION (CDR LST1) LST2) )
            (  T  (CONS (CAR LST1) (UNION (CDR LST1) LST2)) )
      )
   ))
```

в чём косяк моего решения

```
(defun UNI(LISTA LISTB)
    (cond   ((null LISTA) LISTB)
            ((null LISTB) LISTA)
            ( T (setq RESULT nil)
            (loop   ((and (null LISTA) (null LISTB)))
                    (if  (not (MEMBER (car LISTA) LISTB))
                        (cons (car LISTA) RESULT)

                    )
                    (if (not (MEMBER (car LISTB) LISTA))
                        (cons (car LISTB) RESULT)

                    )   
                    (setq LISTA (cdr LISTA))
                    (setq LISTB (cdr LISTB))
            )
            RESULT
            )
    )
)
```

во, решил :)

```
(defun MEMBER(ATM LST)
    (loop
        ((NULL LST) NIL)
        ((EQL ATM (CAR LST)))
        (SETQ LST (CDR LST))
    )
)
(defun UNION(LISTA LISTB)
    (cond   ((null LISTA) LISTB)
            ((null LISTB) LISTA)
            ( T (setq RESULT nil)           
                (loop
                    (setq RESULT (nconc RESULT (cons (car LISTA) '()) ) )
                    ((null (setq LISTA (cdr LISTA))) NIL)
                )
                (loop
                    (if (not (MEMBER (car LISTB) RESULT))
                        (setq RESULT (nconc RESULT (cons (car LISTB) '())))
                    )
                    ((null (setq LISTB (cdr LISTB))) (return RESULT))
                )
            )
    )
)
```

Comment: Ого, Лисп! (Боюсь, правда, что это учебное задание.)

Comment: Мне кажется, что первый вариант — не рабочий. В `COND` последние два значения перепутаны.